# request.body is giving me empty brackets or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch

I am using body parsing middleware. I have installed the `body-parser` library. it seems as though I have tried everything but nothing is working.

here's my server code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bp = require('body-parser');
app.use(bp.json())
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(express.static('/Users/anthonyquesen/Desktop/webzite/drive-download-20201123T191109Z-001/public'))

app.post('/api', async(req,res) => {
    
    console.log(req.body.firstName);
    
    res.json({status: 'ok'})
});

app.listen(3000, ()  =>{
    console.log('server listening at 3000')
});
```

here's my client-side javascript code:

```
let charCreate = function(cCreator){
    let lastName = "name"
    let firstName= "reggy"

    let cCreatorX = cCreator.windowWidth/1.6;
    let charWindow;
    let clickedCreator;
    let bagClicked;
    let dreamJournalClicked;
    cCreator.setup = function()
    {
        cCreator.cCreatorCanvas = cCreator.createCanvas(cCreatorX-200,cCreatorX-200);
        cCan = document.getElementById('charCreate');
        cCreator.cCreatorCanvas.parent(cCan);
        charWindow = characterCreate;
        clickedCreator = false;
        bagClicked = false;
        dreamJournalClicked = false;
    };
    cCreator.draw = function()
    {
        cCreator.clear();
        // cCreator.background(255,50)
        cCreator.image(charWindow,0,-130,cCreatorX-200,cCreatorX);

        if (cCreator.mouseX>cCreatorX/2-170 && cCreator.mouseX<cCreatorX/2 && cCreator.mouseY>cCreatorX/11-22 && cCreator.mouseY<cCreatorX/11-22+190 || bagClicked)
        {
            cCreator.image(seedBagOnHover,cCreatorX/2-170,cCreatorX/11-22,170,190);
        }
        else
        {
            cCreator.image(seedBag,cCreatorX/2-170,cCreatorX/11-22,170,190);
        };

        cCreator.image(dreamJournal,cCreatorX/2+10,cCreatorX/11+80,111,123);
    };
    cCreator.mouseClicked = function()
    {
        clickedCreator = true;
        if (cCreator.mouseX>cCreatorX/2-170 && cCreator.mouseX<cCreatorX/2 && cCreator.mouseY>cCreatorX/11-22 && cCreator.mouseY<cCreatorX/11-22+190 && clickedCreator)
        {
            charWindow = gardenWreath;
            bagClicked = true;
            seedBagSound.play();

            /** API request **/
            fetch('/api', {
                headers:  {'Content-Type' : 'applications/json'},
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({firstName,
                                      lastName,
                                     })
            });
            /** **/

            console.log(JSON.stringify({firstName,lastName}));
        };
    };
    if (cCreator.mouseX>cCreatorX/2+10 && cCreator.mouseX<cCreatorX/2+10+111 && cCreator.mouseY>cCreatorX/11+80 && cCreator.mouseY<cCreatorX/11+80+123)
    {
        charWindow = dreamerWreath;
        dreamjournalClicked = true;
    };
};

let cCreate = new p5(charCreate);
```

The entire function here is the name `spaced/` in instance mode because I'm also using `p5.js` SDK If that has something to do with the code not working as well. there is a Lil more to the code of the client-side like a function that runs cCreator in p5 and other stuff but the main point is the fetch is not sending the code to the terminal. whenever I click the button it sends the post. It knows something sent it just comes back in the terminal as undefined. I'm hoping someone can take a look at this

thank you so much!

Comment: I tried putting the fetch and the variables outside of instance mode/ the p5 and it still came back undefined just in case anyone was thinking that was the problem

Comment: I think it might just be a typo issue. In the content type of the fetch it should be `application/json` instead of `applications/json` (you have an extra 's').

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with p5.js. I think Jeffrey is probably right about the Content-Type typo being a likely candidate for the issue. Check the network tab in your browser's developer tools and you'll be able to confirm that the HTTP POST is being sent with the body you intended.

Comment: literally fixed my whole problem ;D lmao thank you so much I suffered over this and way over complicated it and it was just an s lmao thank you again!!!!!